# What is with the space in between these divs

Tags: html, css, spacing

There is a space in between the two divs at the bottom of my [website](http://rainbowhover.ml). How can I get them to get back together using CSS? The source code is [here](https://github.com/talonbragg/RainbowHover).

Comment: edit your question and hit CTRL + M and post all of your code in the snip box that opens

Comment: Your last H1 (Newsletter Sign Up) needs its top margin set to 0 or its parent div set to `overflow:auto;` or `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the margin for `<h1>`

> Newsletter Sign Up

`h1` is not defined in the CSS. So, it defaults to browser defaults.

As of now `<h1>` has a **top/bottom** **margin** of `32.160px`

try adding the following to your `CSS`

```
h1 {margin: 0 auto}
```